# Tomcat 8 Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class

Tags: java, war, tomcat8

I understand this may be considered a duplicate but none of the other answers worked for me.

I'm deploying a WAR file to ubuntu 14.04. No matter the version I compile with (1.6,1.7,1.8) I continue to get this error. My tomcat versions

```
ubuntu@HOST:/opt/tomcat/bin$ ./version.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
Server built:   May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
Server number:  8.0.23.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.11.0-15-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_111-b14
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

note that it's 1.8.0 but the web mananger says this

[image]

which makes no sense. Note that tomcat7 is currently installed but not running.

Additional Info:

```
ubuntu@HOST:/opt/tomcat/bin$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

[image]

Comment: 52 is 1.8 The jvm is complaining it can not load that class. It seems that you are using an older jvm. Recompile or figure out where the older jvm is coming into play. Are you launching tomcat using an ide or from the command line?

Comment: Should I compile as 1.8? Does tomcat version matter? I'm compiling with eclipse on Windows which uses tomcat8/8.5 and Java 1.8.

Comment: The jar is already in 1.8 format, it is the running jvm where tomcat is running that is older

Comment: How do I point tomcat 8 to java 1.8?

Comment: I guess you don't need the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that you are running tomcat with a 1.7 JVM (see managers output). Double check the way you start tomcat. Do you somewhere set JAVA_HOME in the startup script?

It depends on the OS version and the way tomcat is installed where to find the configuration settings. For a standard install on Ubuntu 16.04 the tomcat 7 settings are found in `/etc/default/tomcat7`.

Comment: where exactly is the startup script? I found this though /usr/share/maven-repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/7.0.52# ls
tomcat-jdbc-7.0.52.jar  tomcat-jdbc-7.0.52.pom

Comment: Your answer was correct. In case someone like me doesn't know where a startup script should be, the path is "/etc/init/tomcat.conf" I needed to edit the line with JAVA_HOME to the newest version I had installed. Can you please add the etc path in your answer.

Comment: @Andy unfortunately, it is not always the same path. It depends on the OS version and the way you install tomcat (as service, as part of some IDE, standalone, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse jdk might be a older version change it as per below steps,

- Right click your project > properties
- Select “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click Edit…
- Select "Workspace Default JRE"
- Click "Installed JREs"
- If you see JRE you want in the list select it (selecting a JDK is OK too)
- If not, click Search…, navigate to Computer > Windows C: > Program Files > Java, then click OK
- Now you should see all installed JREs, select the one you want
  Click OK/Finish.

Comment: Mine was set to jre1.8 by default. This doesn't look like the issue.